# facebook comment plugin disappeared

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, comments

I had the comment plugin working fine, along with the like button and then they stopped working.  I don't believe anything was changed they just stopped showing up.  I switched the like button to the iframe method and it worked but I can't get the comments to show up, I've tried both the html5 and xfbml methods.  When I look through the source in firebug the code is there but nothing is displayed?

Code from my header file.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxx"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxx"/>
```

and

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

comments code

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.liamhildebrand.com/dunn/contact" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Any ideas why the plugin stopped loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the facebook share button? 
Are you sure you're not trying to load this script too?
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share
They interfere with the javascrit sdk, causing all the html5 and xfbml plugins to stop working.
If thats not your case it would be more helpful if you share the url your having problems with.

Comment: First you need to add these:
'og:url','og:title','og:image'
(from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liamhildebrand.com%2Fdunn%2Fcontact)

Then you need to check the plugins and scripts you are loading because they are interferring with facebook's.

The reason I'm saying this again it's because I tested your code and got the same result, after removing all the scripts except the one from Facebook, the comment box was working. Try it yourself and tell me.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thanks, it was a youtube plugin that was causing the problems.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: got the same problem with that URL : http://www.candide.ca/blog/recettes/moelleux-a-la-chataigne.html